# How to keep the snackbar open after action is called

Tags: android, dismiss, snackbar

I use a snackbar to notify the users of my app that they aren't connected to the internet.
I added a "retry" action to the snackbar which re-checks the connection.
I want the snackbar to stay displayed until I dismiss it myself (when an internet connection is found), but I can't get this to work. Whenever I click on the action, the snackbar dismisses.

I've set the duration to indefinite and the snackbar does stay open indefinitely but it dismisses when I click on the action.

I've read online that dismissing the snackbar automatically after clicking on the action hasn't always been the default behavior.

**edit:**

I feel like my question might be badly phrased.
I have a snackbar with an action but I don't want the snackbar to close when the action is executed, which it automatically does atm.

Comment: Why not just create a new snackbar when the user taps "retry"? IMHO it might even be good to wait a second before displaying the new snackbar as visual feedback telling the user that "yes, I retried, but there's still no internet connection". (That's not to say that there's no way of doing what you want)

Comment: So do you want to show snake bar until user manually dismiss it. right?

Comment: Well, the user can dismiss it by swiping, which I don't have a problem with. I just don't want it to close automatically when they click on the action

Comment: There already is visual feedback when checking for a connection, but I suppose I'll end up using a new snackbar like you suggested. I just can't imagine why it wouldn't be easy to just NOT close the snackbar. Like I said, this even used to be the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the OnClickListener set for the button.
First make the snackbar with and set the action with some dummy listener

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"TXT",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { }
    });
```

And then find the button and set your listner

```
snackbar.show();
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) snackbar.getView();
for(int i=0; i< group.getChildCount();i++){
        View v = group.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof Button){
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    YOUR_ACTION();
                }
            });
        }
 }
```

Comment: To add to this, instead of iterating over the ViewGroup you can just use `findViewById`. i.e. `Button actionButton = (Button) snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make("your view".getRootView(), "Annotations", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.setAction("your action", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }, 1);
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
```

After the action is clicked, snackbar will close automatically but with some delay, so if you call `snackbar.show();` directly in the `OnClickListener`, the snack bar will not show. Therefore, to make it show always, give it some delay before showing it. (surprisingly, a one millisecond delay is enough)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
snack = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "Your text", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Button Text") {
                // do something here 
                it.postDelayed({
                    snack.show()
                }, 1000) // Snackbar reappears after 1 second
            }
```